# Avoid a textbox get's focus

Tags: c#, textbox, focus

I'm working in a Windows Form Application, I have a textbox which I want to avoid that gets the focus.

Now I'm using the property Enable but it gives a bad appearance to the form.

Also I tried with this

```
private void txtMyTextbox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ActiveControl = objMyOtherControl;
}
```

But like I'm selecting words of that textbox when the event is raise the textbox lose the selection.

Comment: Making it ReadOnly is actually the proper way to do this. Changed appearance is there to inform the user that he is not supposed to use the control, you shouldn't fight it

Comment: Please refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484326/how-would-you-disable-net-winforms-controls-without-changing-their-appearance

Comment: Why not use a label?

Comment: He want to keeps the ability of selecting text; won't work with a Label.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the textbox unfocusable but you still want be able to select the text, what you are looking for is the **[ReadOnly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.readonly(v=vs.110).aspx)** property.

Here is an extract from the official DOC:

> You can transform an editable Windows Forms text box into a read-only
>   control. For example, the text box may display a value that is usually
>   edited but may not be currently, due to the state of the application.
>   
>  **To create a read-only text box** 
>  
> Set the TextBox control's ReadOnly
>   property to true. With the property set to true, users can still
>   scroll and highlight text in a text box without allowing changes. A
>   Copy command is functional in a text box, but Cut and Paste commands
>   are not. 
>  Note   The ReadOnly property **only affects user interaction at
>   run time**. You can still change text box contents **programmatically** at
>   run time by changing the Text property of the text box.